# Why does AWK not treat this array index as a number unless I use int()?

Tags: arrays, bash, awk

I have genomics files of the following type:

```
$ cat test-file_long.txt 
2 41647 A G
2 45895 A G
2 45953 T C
2 224919 A G
2 230055 C G
2 233239 A G
2 234130 T G
2 23454 T C
```

When I use the following short AWK script, it does not return all of the elements which are greater than the element used in the if statement:

```
{
    a[$2]
}
END{
    for (i in a){
    if(i > 45895) 
    print i
    }
}
```

The script returns this:

```
$ awk -f practice.awk test-file_long.txt 
45953
```

However, when I change the if statement using int(), it returns the lines that are in fact greater than, as I want:

```
{
    a[$2]
}
END{
    for (i in a){
    if(int(i) > 45895) 
    print i
    }
}
```

Result:

```
$ awk -f practice.awk test-file_long.txt 
233239
230055
234130
224919
45953
```

It appears it is only making the comparison with the first digit, and if they are the same it looks at the next digit, but it does not process the whole number. Can someone explain to me what it is about the internal mechanism of the associative array that it does not make the numeric >/< comparison unless I specify that I want the int() of the array element? What if my array elements were floats and int() was not an option?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Array keys in awk are strings, so alphabetical comparison is being done here. In your first example, `459` is greater than `458` alphabetically, so it passes the test.

If your only goal is to print the lines whose 2nd column is `> 45895` *numerically*, this would do:

```
awk '$2 > 45895' test-file_long.txt
```

Variables change type depending on the context in which they are evaluated. So by putting a variable in an explicitly numeric context, it will be treated as such. @glenn's suggestion of `i+0` demonstrates this perfectly.

Alternatively, the [unary plus operator](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Arithmetic-Ops.html) `+i` can be used to convert an expression to a number. So your longer example could be changed to:

```
awk '{a[$2]} END { for (i in a) { if (+i > 45895) print i } }' test-file_long.txt
```

Comment: I see, thanks, Tom. More generally, is there a way to convert a string to a float in AWK?

Comment: @isosceleswheel, add zero: `if (i+0 > 45895) print i`

Comment: @glenn great suggestion, I've added it to my answer

Comment: @glenn actually I can beat that by a character with `+i` ;)

Comment: Is +i (i+0) implicitly?

Comment: @isosceleswheel No, it's just the unary plus operator, [which converts the expression to a number](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Arithmetic-Ops.html).

Comment: I was wondering why you don't have any Nice Answer or Enlightened badge yet!

Comment: @fedorqui it's the system trying to keep me down ;)