# AWK nested for-loop, "10-89 less than 9?"

Tags: for-loop, awk, nested

I'm trying to use nested for-loop in AWK but it seems like I'm hitting a problem with the number comparison of an array and a variable.

Example:

**Creating array**

```
str[0]="a"; str[1]="b"; str[2]="c"; str[3]="d"; str[4]="e";
str[5]="f"; str[6]="g"; str[7]="h"; str[8]="i"; str[9]="j";
str[10]="k"; str[11]="l"; str[12]="m"; str[13]="n"
```

**Printing content, one index per line, indenting  for each line**

```
for(i in str) {
  printf "index " i ":"
  for(j=0;j<=i;j++) {
    printf "<tab " j ">"
  }
  printf str[i] "\n"
}
```

**Output**

```
index 0:<tab 0>a
index 1:<tab 0><tab 1>b
index 2:<tab 0><tab 1><tab 2>c
index 3:<tab 0><tab 1><tab 2><tab 3>d
index 4:<tab 0><tab 1><tab 2><tab 3><tab 4>e
index 5:<tab 0><tab 1><tab 2><tab 3><tab 4><tab 5>f
index 6:<tab 0><tab 1><tab 2><tab 3><tab 4><tab 5><tab 6>g
index 7:<tab 0><tab 1><tab 2><tab 3><tab 4><tab 5><tab 6><tab 7>h
index 8:<tab 0><tab 1><tab 2><tab 3><tab 4><tab 5><tab 6><tab 7><tab 8>i
index 9:<tab 0><tab 1><tab 2><tab 3><tab 4><tab 5><tab 6><tab 7><tab 8><tab 9><tab 10><tab 11><tab 12><tab 13><tab 14><tab 15><tab 16><tab 17><tab 18><tab 19><tab 20><tab 21><tab 22><tab 23><tab 24><tab 25><tab 26><tab 27><tab 28><tab 29><tab 30><tab 31><tab 32><tab 33><tab 34><tab 35><tab 36><tab 37><tab 38><tab 39><tab 40><tab 41><tab 42><tab 43><tab 44><tab 45><tab 46><tab 47><tab 48><tab 49><tab 50><tab 51><tab 52><tab 53><tab 54><tab 55><tab 56><tab 57><tab 58><tab 59><tab 60><tab 61><tab 62><tab 63><tab 64><tab 65><tab 66><tab 67><tab 68><tab 69><tab 70><tab 71><tab 72><tab 73><tab 74><tab 75><tab 76><tab 77><tab 78><tab 79><tab 80><tab 81><tab 82><tab 83><tab 84><tab 85><tab 86><tab 87><tab 88><tab 89>j
index 10:<tab 0><tab 1>k
index 11:<tab 0><tab 1>l
index 12:<tab 0><tab 1>m
index 13:<tab 0><tab 1>n
```

The printout clearly stay the **i=10** but even though **j** becomes **11 [ for(j=0;j<=i;j++) ]**

Any suggestions? :)

Comment: It must be doing a string comparison instead of a numeric one.  Force its hand with the condition `j <= i + 0`. It is probably because array subscripts in `awk` are strings.  It is pretty good about converting automatically, but doesn't always get it right the way you want it.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why does AWK not treat this array index as a number unless I use int()?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23272927/why-does-awk-not-treat-this-array-index-as-a-number-unless-i-use-int)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Problem**

The `j<=i` does a string comparison. So `10` is less than `9` is expected and so on for `11, 12...89`

**Solution**

You can cast the value of string to an integer by adding a `0` to the string. That is

```
j<=i+0
```

The awk does a conversion to int on the data, `i`

```
for(i in str) {
  printf "index " i ":"
  for(j=0;j<=i+0;j++) {
    printf "<tab " j ">"
  }
  printf str[i] "\n"
}
```

[**Read more on awk type conversions**](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Conversion.html#Conversion)